# Disable multicore in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, multi-core

In windows 7 msconfig can disable different cores of the Operating System after a restart as per this [link](http://sevenforums.com/tutorials/66504-processors-limit-number-used-windows-7-a.html).
Is there a similar option in ubuntu that can explicitly disable all cores but one?

Comment: See here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/10-boot-time-parameters-you-should-know-about-the-linux-kernel.html - The option is "maxcpus". You can also enable/disable CPU cores while the system is running. See here: http://www.absolutelytech.com/2011/08/01/how-to-disable-cpu-cores-in-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the configuration file

> sudo vim /etc/default/grub

Find the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append this as below example maxcpus=n (n number of CPU) want to enable

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" maxcpus=1"

After saving the file run the below command

> sudo update-grub2

When you reboot, linux will run on 1 cores